# Can the Finder Dock be fixed to show all icons of aliases instead of some?

Tags: macos, dock, icon

I have a folder in my dock full of aliases to applications. When I add a new alias, the icon doesn't usually show up in the Dock folder:

[image]

but the icons are there in the Finder window for the same folder in every case. Usually the icons will show up eventually (with no clear indication of what triggers the fix), but these 4 apps have been stuck without an icon for some time and through a reboot. I have this now on Mountain Lion, but the same thing happened in Lion.

Does anyone know how to fix things (preventative or remedial) so the Dock will display icons properly?

Comment: Have you tried anything to fix this? Does it persist after you log out and then in again? After a reboot?

Comment: Yes, it persists after I reboot. I just discovered that if I drag the folder out of the Dock to remove it, then I drag it from the Finder back into the dock, the icons start appearing.

Comment: My guess is the dock process is either over eager and decides the app has no icon during the copy process or has a bug in finding the icon after it's added to the folder that consists of aliases. If you find a good workaround or solution, please post it here as an answer and accept it. We love people reporting an answer so much that we have a special holiday hat for that.

Comment: Why not use Launchpad? (Or are you on Snow Leopard?)

Comment: I have way too many apps for Launchpad to be useful. I also have a special folder in the dock for each of my kids which just has the stuff they're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this by dragging the folder out of the Dock to remove it, then dragging the folder back from the Finder into the Dock. I'd still love to know if there's something that would fix it in place, but this is working for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Does making a folder of aliases in, say, Documents, and using them from there - rather than direct aliases from apps - does that help?